# Polymer Inconsistent Nesting of HTML Elements

Tags: polymer

I am facing a weird issue with relation to the nesting of HTML tags within a Polymer element.

Here is my polymer element:

```
<template>
     <table>
        <tr>
            <data-table-row columns="{{headerColumns}}" isHeader=true></data-table-row>
        </tr>
        <template repeat="{{row in tableData}}">
            <tr>
                <data-table-row columns="{{row}}"></data-table-row>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </table>
</template>
```

data-table-row is another polymer element that I created:

```
<template>
    <template if="{{isHeader}}">
        <th><paper-checkbox for></paper-checkbox></th>
        <template repeat="{{column in columns}}">
            <th>{{column.value}}</th>
        </template>
    </template>
    <template if="{{!isHeader}}">
        <td><paper-checkbox for></paper-checkbox></td>
        <template repeat="{{column in columns}}">
            <td>{{column.value}}</td>
        </template>
    </template>
</template>
```

The rendering is fine - I get a header row and a list of other rows below it. But when I look at the markup, it is weird. The header row is "outside" the table tag. Something like this:

```
<data-table-row>Header Stuff...</data-table-row>
<table>
    <tr><data-table-row>Table Row 1</data-table-row></tr>
    <tr><data-table-row>Table Row 2</data-table-row></tr>
    <tr><data-table-row>Table Row 3</data-table-row></tr>
</table>
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?